# Grails, Spring Security core, change user authority

Tags: grails, spring-security

I generated Role, User and UserRole class using the Spring Security Core Plugin. I want to set the users role directly in the user-creation-process. I added a "Role" field in User but don't know how and where I should set the entry in UserRole.

Is there anything else to implement like reauthentication to update a users role afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

You should delete link to Role from User and use next code, after creating User and Role:

```
UserRole.create(user,role,true)
```

Where user your created user, role your created role, and true is indicated that userRole should create with flush:true
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes its works!!! thanks, this is my code in a Service:

```
public String updateUser(long userId, String username, String password, long roleId){
    Object[] args = [messageSource.getMessage('spring.security.ui.login.username',null, null),username];
    def user = User.get(userId);
    def userTemp = User.findAllByUsername(username);

    if(userTemp.isEmpty() || userTemp.get(0).id == userId){
        def role = Role.get(roleId);
        user.username = username;
        user.roleId = roleId;
        if (password != ''){
            user.password = password;
        }
        user.save(flush:true);
        UserRole.create(user,role,true);
        return "<span class='successMessage'><strong>" + messageSource.getMessage("message.common.record.saved.successfully", args, null) + "</strong></span>";
    } else {
        return "<span class='warnMessage'><strong>" + messageSource.getMessage("message.common.register.exist", args,null) + "</strong></span>";
    }       
}
```